# variable value doesn't increase

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, postback

This is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Add.Click += (source, e1) =>
        {
            count ++;
            Response.Write(count);
        };
    }

}
```

I want to increase the counter of `count` as I click on the button , from 0 to the number of times i click the button . Add is the name of the static button . However if i put my codes outside of `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` it could only print 1 . But when i put into `!Page.IsPostBack` , it print 0

Comment: You must understand asp.net is stateless. You must figure out how and where you can store the states. The variable "count" counts.

Answer (score 2):

`count` is a local variable and is reinitialized everytime on Page Load. 
There are number of other ways to do it like Session Variable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        Add.Click += (source, e1) =>
        {
            if(Session["count"]==null)
                Session["count"]=1;
            else
                Session["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]) + 1
            Response.Write(Session["count"].ToString()); 

        };
    }

}
```

Other state management techniques can also be used like **ViewSate**  to implement this.
Difference between Session and Viewstate variable is that once you move to another page , **Viewstate** values are destroyed

Comment: your sample for `VB` or `C#`?

Comment: its still the same , it will only run once

Comment: vb and c# have some differents :-) like _VB_:`CInt(Session("count"))` and _C#_:`Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"])`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should behave that way.

Your `count` variable is captured in closure that leaves through single request. Initial value is `0` and in case of postback caused by `click` it will be changed once.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @user2376998 - yes - store value in SessionState as in mhasan answer, view state, hidden fields, DB, query parameters,...

Answer (score 0):

When you try add something dynamicaly with asp, you need do it on every request, because on every request rebuild tree controls and all controls create again.
So for solve you need add `Click` event on every request, i.e remove checking `!Page.IsPostBack`

Also as say [@mhasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21620113/2881286) you need use session or something else for store value between requests, because if you remove `IsPostBack` you will be create lambda with closure on every requests

**UPDATE:** sample

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Add.Click += (source, e1) =>
    {
        Session["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]??0) + 1;
        Response.Write(Session["count"].ToString()); 

    };
}
```

Comment: Yes i have used Session and place it ouside of !Page.IsPostBack but it will only run once , means the value will be 2 if the initial value is 1 .